# Setpup/export envirnonment variable from within gradle bruildscript

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a buildscript that has like 20 different tasks. Each tasks executes some commands, each task needs some environment variables. Some environment variables are common for all tasks, some environment variables are not. Is there a way in gradle to set up those common environment variables on top of all task? or place the environment variables in a method/task and invoke it as a first step inside each other tasks which require those environment variables?

```
task task1 (type:Exec) {
      environment COMMON_ENV, VALUE1
      commandLine 'touch', 'xyz100.txt'
}

task task2 (type:Exec) {
      environment COMMON_ENV, VALUE1
      commandLine 'touch', 'xyz200.txt'
}
```

So in this example both task1, and task2 needs the same environment variable COMMON_ENV. So how can I define it in a common place instead of defining in each task.

Remember its not a java project.

the following does not work to set env variable to all tasks

```
task setEnv(type: Exec) {
      environment COMMON_ENV, VALUE1
}
task task1 (type:Exec, dependsOn: setEnv) {
      commandLine 'touch', 'xyz100.txt'//this task does not know COMMON_ENV, though it 'dependsOn' setEnv task
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set some common properties for all tasks with the same type, all you need is to configure them additionally, just like so:

```
tasks.withType(Exec) {
    environment COMMON_ENV, VALUE1
}

task task1 (type:Exec) {
      commandLine 'touch', 'xyz100.txt'
}

task task2 (type:Exec) {
      commandLine 'touch', 'xyz200.txt'
}
```

Note, you can add `tasks.withType(Exec)` into the `allprojects` or `subprojects` closure to configure not only current project, but all your project or subproject, if needed.